# Force autoinc field with MySqlDataAdapter/MySqlCommandBuilder

Tags: c#, mysql, ado.net

With C# and MySQL ADO.NET connector, I use MySqlDataAdapter and MySqlCommandBuilder to update a table.

Is it possible to temporarily force an autoinc field ?

```
  DataRow row = ...
  row["Id"] = 90; // force autoinc value
  using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = ...)
  {
    MySqlCommandBuilder builder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(adapter);
    int result = adapter.Update(new DataRow[] { row });
    // The inserted ID is 20 and not 90...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, so long as you explicitly specify the value as in the code example that you provided, it will work. Off course it will fail if a duplicate value is specified.

The auto increment is only applied to an insert if you omitted the value or the value is NULL or 0 or DEFAULT.

Comment: Unfortunately, as you can see in my example above, it does work.
MySQL use the next value in the autoincrement field...

Answer (score 0):

@A.Baudouin I think you meant to say "Unfortunately, as you can see in my example above, it does **not** work"! Did you ever find a solution? I had exactly the same problem but found that it works OK if you use MySql Workbench to modify the value. All the Workbench does is a normal `UPDATE` command, so I am guessing this is a problem of `MySqlAdapter`, or maybe a "feature"! I ended up updating the database directly like:

```
MySqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(myConnection, "UPDATE MyTable SET Id = 90 WHERE Id = 7", null);
```

(or however you want to identify the correct row with WHERE). This works OK.